# PHP, error set static variable for class instance inside class

Tags: php, class, methods, static, singleton

I'm trying call class method inside another class.

```
<?php
class A {
    public static $instant = null;
    public static $myvariable = false;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function initial() {
        if (static::$instant === null) {
            $self = __CLASS__;
            static::$instant = new $self;
        }
        return static::$instant; // A instance
    }
}

class B {
    private $a;

    function __construct($a_instance) {
        $this->a = $a_instance;
    }

    public function b_handle() {
        // should be:
        $this->a::$myvariable = true;
        // but:
        // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

        // try with:
        // $this->a->myvariable = true;
        // but:
        // Strict Standards: Accessing static property A::$myvariable as non static
    }
}

// in file.php
$b = new B(A::initial());
$b->b_handle();

var_dump(A::$myvariable);
```

for now, my alternative is:

```
<?php
class A {
    public function set_static($var,$val) {
        static::$$var = $val;
    }
}
```

so:

```
$this->a->set_static('myvariable',true);
```

what should I do ?
what is happen ?
am I wrong ?

why I cannot set **myvariable** as static variable direcly from **B** class ?

*sorry for bad english.*

Comment: This is highly unusual code, and I think there are several issues here that are confusing you and other possible answerers here. Try putting this into your `__construct()` method for `B` and you'll see one of several problems immediately: `var_dump($a_instance);` I get `NULL` printed out, so your code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `$myvariable` is a static property. Which is assigned using a `classname::` syntax.

Comment: And `static::$instant !== null` - so if it's **NOT** null you create new one. And if it's null you just return null? Are you sure?

Comment: oh, sorry wrong code in A::initial(), should be if (static::$instant === null)

Comment: @u_mulder , i'did. A instantce from A::initial()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

> A property declared as static **cannot** be accessed with an instantiated **class object** (though a static method can).

So, you **cannot** in anyway set `static` property from class instance.

As an option you can add some setter, which set your static variable:

```
public function setMyVar($value) {
    static::$myvariable = $value;
}

$this->a->setMyVar(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call,

```
$this->a::$myvariable = true;
```

The PHP manual says,

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

This is why you are unable to assign static property through an object.

Simply do this:

```
A::$myvariable = true;
```

Here's the reference:

- [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: but, in my 'real' code, I using namespace, and i wouldn't re-import (in this case ) A class using 'use'